# Calling Firebase Cloud Messaging from server does not work

Tags: php, curl, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just developed a firebase web app server. I am sending notifications and everything seems okay but in my android app no notifications are received. If I send a notification from firebase console it comes to my android app. However I want to send it from my web app.

Here is my php code for web app:

```
public function sendMessage($data,$target=null){
        //FCM api URL
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        //api_key available in Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING -> Server key
        $server_key = 'S6GzaCUhIbS6GzaCAIzaSyJtkQLzl3FCUhIbUhIbS6Gza8A';

        //$fields = array();
        //$fields['data'] = $data;
        if(is_array($target)){
            $fields['registration_ids'] = $target;
        }

            $fields = array(
        'notification' => array('title' => 'Working Good', 'body' => 'That is all we want'),
        'data' => array('message' => "melaapa")
    );



        //header with content_type api key
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type:application/json',
          'Authorization:key='.$server_key
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        var_dump($result);
        return $result;
        }
```

The output of

> var_dump($result)

is

> string(3) "to "

What should the reponse be for a working firebase server or how can I understand that my firebase server is working fine?

Comment: See the expected response format here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#response

Comment: thanks sir you really helped me :)